# QWebView displays "Network Access is disabled" and Qt Network Error 99

Tags: qwebview, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

Running with:

- Ubuntu 22.04.
- Qt 5.12.8
- OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31

QWebView is showing this error:
[image: Screenshot 2024-01-17 at 9.28.49 AM.jpg]

This Url works with no issues in the Firefox browser but QWebView seems to have an issue.

Here's the QNetworkReply info from the logs:

```
Failed URL: "https://dev-81029421.okta.com/app/dev-81029421_442710740samlidp_1/exkanm3x81DrxatKc5d7/sso/saml"

NetworkError: QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError
http status = 0
httpStatusMsg = ""
```

Here is my QWebView setup. I double checked everything and it looks correct. Not sure what to try next:

```
QWebView * m_samlView = new QWebView();

// Set User Agent
QString browserUserAgent = m_samlView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent").toString();
m_pUserAgentPage = new UserAgentWebPage();
m_pUserAgentPage->setBrowserUserAgent(browserUserAgent);
m_samlView->setPage(m_pUserAgentPage);

// Network Access Manager
m_pNetworkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
m_pNetworkAccessManager->setNetworkAccessible(QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible);
m_samlView->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(m_pNetworkAccessManager);

// Network Proxy
checkProxy(); 
QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(m_networkProxy);
m_samlView->page()->networkAccessManager()->setProxy(m_networkProxy);

// Enable Javascript
m_samlView->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);

 // Enable web inspector
m_samlView->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);

QWebInspector inspector;
inspector.setPage(m_samlView->page());
inspector.setVisible(true);

// Setup Network Cookie Jar
m_pCookieJar = new CookieJar();
m_samlView->page()->networkAccessManager()->setCookieJar(m_pCookieJar);

// Clear cache and cookies
clearCacheAndCookies();

// QWebView: Connect signals/slots
connect(m_samlView, SIGNAL(urlChanged(const QUrl&)),
        this,       SLOT(onUrlChanged(const QUrl&)));
connect(m_samlView, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),
        this,       SLOT(onLoadFinished(bool)));

// QNetworkAccessManager: Connect signals/slots
connect(m_pNetworkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this,                    SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
connect(m_pNetworkAccessManager, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError>&)),
        this,                    SLOT(onSslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError>&)));
```

Comment: Does the network connection is active and functioning properly? and did you test your webview with a simple web page?

Comment: Yeah webview works with a simple web page.